# IOS Track User Location Map kit

Tags: objective-c, core-location

How i can track user location using CoreLocation and MapKit? I place a point on the map. When the application is minimized to check whether the user has not reached the destination. If you reached to withdraw the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Allow your application to run in background
- In background, start your get geolocation thread active to get current location (on timely basis, after each 10 secs)
- If the results gets approx. equal value (for ex.: 2 km. radius) to your location, then throw a local notification from that app.

To do all this, you will surely find documentation over web, topics are:

- Allow your app to run in background
- Fetch user's current location (Start this thread in background delegate method)
- Match location
- Fire local notification

These are the base flow points, hope this will help you for initial start up.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, it would be great if you upvote the same.

Comment: Yes, i set point on map. And then when user going app must track user geolocation